# Treeview model properties are null in delegate warning

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `TreeView`

```
TreeView {
        id: dndView
        rowDelegate: Item {
            height: 30
        }
        itemDelegate:  dndDelegate
        model: myModel
        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            resizable: true
        }
}
```

and its delegate which **does** work

```
Rectangle {
    id: dragRect
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    color: 'gray'
    width: dndView.width - 20
    height: 30
    Image {
        id: menuItemImage
        anchors.verticalCenter:parent.verticalCenter
        source:model.CommandIcon
    }
    Text {
        anchors.left:menuItemImage.right
        anchors.verticalCenter:parent.verticalCenter
        text:model.CommandTitle
        font.pixelSize: 14
    }
```

Roles in C++ file:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> MenuTreeModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TitleRole] = "CommandTitle";
    roles[IconRole] = "CommandIcon";
    return roles;
}
```

It displays text and icon correctly but nevertheless when I expand the items or close the application I have warnings:

> qrc:/DraggableRectangle.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot read property 'CommandIcon' of null qrc:/DraggableRectangle.qml:20: TypeError: Cannot read property 'CommandTitle' of null*

What's wrong with it?

Comment: I think it would help to have a short, compilable example. Can you get all of the C++ into main.cpp, remove all unnecessary stuff, move the QML delegate inline, etc?

Comment: Or if you don't want to do that, you could try `text: model ? model.CommandTitle : ""`, but that's just a workaround.

Comment: @Mitch the same with inline delegate. Main looks like int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

 QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
 MenuTreeModel model(&engine);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
 ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);

 engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}

Comment: I'm just saying that no one can run your code, so all we can do is guess at what the problem might be judging from the snippets you've posted. The inline delegate suggestion was just so that it would all be in one QML file. We still don't know what your MenuTreeModel looks like, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the warnings only appear on specific events, it may mean the model is destroyed or not yet created when your QML view tries to use it.

E.g. if the model is destroyed before the view when you close the application, the view still tries to use a destroyed object for a short time (before it's destroyed too).

Try this :

```
text: model ? model.CommandTitle : ""
```

Comment: I've changed the layout, now they appear only when I close (earlier it happened while expanding nodes as well, weird). Anyway your solution should work.

Comment: I think that this is really just a workaround, like I mentioned in the comments of the question. If you want a proper solution, you'll need to post a runnable example.

Comment: If you want you can track down in your code where the model is destoyed, and where the view is, and make sure the model is destroyed after the view (not sure if it's easily doable with a QML view). But I'm fine with simply telling my view not to use an undefined object, especially if it's just to avoid a warning on application exit.

Answer (score 0):

Its the anchor in the root of your delegate.

```
anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter.
```

You can't anchor the left hand side of a TreeView's delegate. Remove that line and I bet it will work.

Comment: how do anchors relate to model? I removed them and apparently still have the same warning